# Preposiciones para dirección

Tags: preposiciones

Me encontré escribiendo esta frase:

```
Ella comenzó a correr hacia la dirección en la que él había apuntado.
```

Sin embargo, siento que las preposiciones son correctas de forma independiente, y no encuentro la forma en que tengan sentido juntas, por las siguientes razones:

- ¿Uno `corre hacia una dirección`, o `corre a una dirección`?
- ¿Uno `apunta a una dirección` o `apunta hacia una dirección`?
- ¿Cuál es correcto: `en la que él había apuntado` o `a la que él había apuntado`?

De alguna forma todas suenan sinónimas para mi, y no estoy seguro de cómo distinguir el caso correcto del incorrecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Correr **en** una dirección" es lo más natural, para significar una orientación general (dirección y sentido) (ej: en dirección norte).

"Correr **hacia** " se usa más bien para significar un destino puntual ("Corrió hacia su casa")

"Correr **a** (un lugar)" suena un poco más coloquial y menos correcto, aunque es usada como reemplazo de "Correr hacia" ("Corrió a su casa").
Tiene el problema de que puede confundirse con otros significados de "correr" en los que el complemento es objecto indirecto o directo (correr=perseguir algo o a alguien, correr=desplazar algo)

"Apuntar en/a/hacia": vale más o menos lo mismo. Pero es verdad que "apuntar" se usa en general para "puntos" (como la palabra sugiere) que para direcciones, pero el habla común no es estricta con esto.

"en la que él había apuntado" o "a la que él había apuntado"?
NO están mal, prefiero la primero. Pero en esa frase, ambas me suenan algo recargadas. Yo preferiría:

> Ella comenzó a correr en la dirección que él había indicado.
>
> Ella comenzó a correr en la dirección que él había señalado.

Answer (score 1):

- Uno "corre/va en una dirección".
- Uno "apunta hacia algo".
- La frase sería:

> Ella comenzó a correr en la dirección hacia la que él había apuntado.

Answer (score 0):

```
Si -> Uno corre hacia una dirección
NO -> o corre a una dirección

No -> Uno apunta a una dirección
Si -> apunta hacia una dirección

No -> en la que él había apuntado
Si -> a la que él había apuntado
```